# Validation failed for one or more entities in Entity Framework for nullable boolean property

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6

My class looks like this, I added new property `IsModified` which can be nullable. I can create a new entity of type `A` using only Name and Key property, but when I try to update key for any existing records for which `IsModified` is null in db, I get this error from Entity Framework:

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException. The `IsModified` field is required on context.SaveChangesAsync().

Model class:

```
public class A
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public bool? IsModified { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        this.IsModified = false;
    }
}
```

SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A]
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Key] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [IsModified] [bit] NULL,
 )
```

I am using Entity Framework v6 with a code-first approach. `[IsModified]` is nullable, so I am not sure why the field is still required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was boolean value cannot be configured as null. It will always be considered required by EF. I changed `IsModified bit null` to `IsModified bit not null default 1` .And updated the existing records with default value using Migration.
 Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/required-optional.

Answer (score 0):

How do you migrate ? Clear the table dbo.__MigrationHistory. Very often I experience similar problems with EF, and in most cases cleaning this table helps. (It'll definitely work, I recreate this situation in my computer)